# Executing logout with Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a button on my layout, it should make logout when clicked.
Layout:

```
<form action="/template/logout" method="POST">
   <input class="btn acc_exit" name="btn_logout" type="submit" value="logout" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionLogout(){
    Yii::$app->user->logout();
    return Yii::$app->response->redirect('/login');
}
```

i get this error when clicking
[msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGqPg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `CSRF-TOKEN` when using `POST` requests add this inside your form. CSRF protection is enabled by default so what you need is to submit a token along with all your requests. Usually it's done via hidden field:

```
<form action="/template/logout" method="POST">
   <input id="form-token" type="hidden" name="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfParam?>"
           value="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfToken?>"/>
   <input class="btn acc_exit" name="btn_logout" type="submit" value="logout" />
</form>
```